# CakePhp How can I save http reponse (in xml format) to the server?

Tags: xml, cakephp, httpresponse, cakephp-2.x

In my CakePhp 2.10 project I've created an action to generate an xml file and the relative view in the xml folder to render it in the correct format.

I am able to download it from the client with the command: `$this->response->download($filename);` but **how can I save that xml file to a server folder instead**?

I need it because I want to generate some files with a single request, and then compress them in a zip file.

Thanks

Comment: Is there something wrong with `file_put_contents`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I am searching for some specific CakePhp function.
Actually I made it with HttpSocket->get function and it works, but I think it can be imporoved.

Comment: Cake has [`folder and file` utility classes](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html), but they're deprecated for removal in v5. Why add a wrapper around something so simple as writing data to a file?